# Random Iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would Correct Next script paragraph Stay Way I Need.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function randomIframe(obj){
var ends = new Array();
ends[0] = "http://www.terra.com.br";
ends[1] = "http://www.uol.com.br";
ends[2] = "http://www.bol.com.br";
ends[3] = "http://www.cade.com.br";
ends[4] = "http://www.baixaki.com.br";

var i = Math.round(Math.random()*ends.length-1);

obj.location.replace(ends[i]);

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="randomIframe(publicidade)">

<iframe name="publicidade" width="500" height="100"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering if you have some form of `<iframe>` stay within the same script, not below the body which `document.write` use within the script and `window.onload = random_iframe` for example. To stay just something inside of `<script>` to `</script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using `document.write()`. Use `document.createElement()` and `.appendChild()`.

```js
function randomIframe() {
  var ends = [
    "http://www.terra.com.br",
    "http://www.uol.com.br",
    "http://www.bol.com.br",
    "http://www.cade.com.br",
    "http://www.baixaki.com.br"
  ];

  var i = Math.floow(Math.random() * ends.length);

  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = ends[i];
  iframe.style.height = '300px';
  iframe.style.width = '400px';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

}

window.onload = randomIframe;
```

Comment: But if so, how will change the attributes of the iframe? My iframe must have size 400 x 300 , it will be as a widget on the side of the blog.
I tested the site and the iframe appeared below the site .

http://grandebotaovermelho.com.br/wordpress/

Comment: I added height and width to my answer, you can add other attributes similarly.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how I can esolher where this iframe will be created ?
He is appearing at the end of my website. I would have to choose a div ? I have an empty div with id = banner
I add other attributes similarly..

Comment: You can put it anywhere you want, just call `appendChild` on the node you want to add it to. I think you need to learn Javascript basics, or you're going to be coming back here for every single line of code you write.\

Comment: `document.getElementById('banner').appendChild(iframe)`

Comment: It looks like this randomizer `var i = Math.round(Math.random() * ends.length - 1);` will suddenly produce negative numbers which will cause 'undefined' values. Am I right? How can I avoid this?

Comment: by the way, here's my proposal: `var i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) % ends.length);`

Comment: @AlexeyBogomolov The usual way to select a random index of an array is `Math.floor(Math.random() * ends.length)`. I've updated my answer. I originally just copied that line from the OP's code without even investigating it, since it wasn't related to the actual problem they were having.